# Sending Data to Kerberos Enabled Kafka cluster from scala Client

Tags: scala, akka, apache-kafka, kerberos

I am writing akka, Kafka Producer in scala, I am trying to send messages to kafka broker from scala kafka client and issue is that broker is not getting these message I verified it by starting kafka consumer from command line. Kafka producer and consumer are working fine from command prompt. Kafka is Kerberos and SASL_PlainText security enabled.

Please find below my conf file,client code and application logs. I think there must be some issue while connecting to Kerberos from code.

Scala Client:

```
package com.ABC.adds.producer

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.kafka.ProducerSettings
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import com.ABC.adds.models.Models.GMMOfaq
import com.ABC.adds.producer.serializer.ModelSerializer
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord, RecordMetadata}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object faqProducer extends App with LazyLogging{

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  implicit val system = ActorSystem.create("adds-faq-producer", config)
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(system, new ByteArraySerializer, new ModelSerializer[PPOfaq](classOf[PPOfaq]))
  .withBootstrapServers("jbt12324.systems.pfk.ABC:3382")
     .withProperty(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
      .withProperty("zookeeper.connect","jbt234234.systems.pfk.ABC:2341,jbt234.systems.pfk.ABC:234,jbt1234324.systems.pfk.ABC:2234")
      .withProperty(CommonClientConfigs.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "1")

  val xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver)
  val personString: String = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("PPOfaq.xml")).mkString
  xstream.alias("faq", classOf[PPOfaq])
  val ppofaq: PPOfaq = xstream.fromXML(personString).asInstanceOf[PPOfaq]

  logger.info(s"Producer Configuration is : {} ", producerSettings.toString)
  logger.info(s"Sending message : {}", ppofaq)

  logger.info("KafkaProducer Send first fetching Partitions for topics")
  val  kafkaProducer  = producerSettings.createKafkaProducer()
  kafkaProducer.partitionsFor("asp.adds.ppo.pems")
  val done1 = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], PPOfaq]("asp.adds.ppo.pems", ppofaq))
  val recordMetaData : RecordMetadata = done1.get()

    logger.info("Topic is :  " + recordMetaData.topic() +" partition is : "+ recordMetaData.partition() +" offset is : "+ recordMetaData.offset() )

  logger.info("KafkaProdcuer Send first fetching Partitions for topics end")

  val done = Source.single(ppofaq)
    .map { elem =>
      new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], PPOfaq]("asp.adds.ppo.pems", ppofaq)
    }
    .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))

  done onComplete {
  case Success(s) => {
    logger.info(s"The producer has sent a message to the topic: asp.adds.ppo.pems!!")
  }
  case Failure(e) => {
    logger.error("Erorr occured while producing Topic", e)
    e.printStackTrace()
    e.fillInStackTrace()
    e.getCause
    e.getMessage
  }
}
}
```

This is Kafka_Client Conf file I am using for Kerberos authentication:

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
doNotPrompt=true
useTicketCache=false
useKeyTab=true
serviceName="kafka"
principal="pqr@ASND.ADROOT.ABC"
keyTab="/home/pqr/.pqr.headless.keytab"
debug=true
client=true;
};
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  doNotPrompt=true
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=false
  serviceName="zookeeper"
  principal="pqr@ASND.ADROOT.ABC"
  keyTab="/home/pqr/.pqr.headless.keytab"
  debug=true;
};
```

This is the application log I am getting when I run my jar on cluster:
Application Logs:

```
 [asd-sasds-addsk@jbt32423 ResourceBundle]$ java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_client_jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.debug=logincontext,gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser, -jar adds-producer.jar
            [Policy Parser]: creating policy entry for expanded java.ext.dirs path:
                    file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-0.b16.el6_6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/*
            [Policy Parser]: creating policy entry for expanded java.ext.dirs path:
                    file:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext/*
    14:44:56.520 [main] INFO  c.h.adds.producer.addsProducer$ - Producer Configuration is : akka.kafka.ProducerSettings@35432107
    14:44:56.523 [main] INFO  c.h.adds.producer.addsProducer$ - Sending message : PPOadds(PIC_EVENT,01/06/2016,26/10/2016,ASSIGNED,asd_asdasd_ERRORED,asd,asdMSR,High,CASE-3,CASE-4,CASE-1,CASE-2,,CustomAttributes(GCAL,PTS Only,,DTF_INT_WORKFLOWS_COMPLETE,16065763,2495921,12,CreditDefaultSwap,CreditDefaultSwap,VERIFIED_asdasd,ABCUSA,asdCDS))
    14:44:56.524 [main] INFO  c.h.adds.producer.addsProducer$ - KafkaProducer Send first fetching Partitions for topics
    configfile: reading file:/home/asdasd-asdasdds-adds-asda/adasd-erer/hfgh/kafka_client_jaas.conf
    configparser:   Reading next config entry: KafkaClient
    configparser:           com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule, REQUIRED
    configparser:                   principal=234-dfgd-adds-asd@asdad.ADROOT.ABC
    configparser:                   debug=true
    configparser:                   doNotPrompt=true
    configparser:                   keyTab=/home/asdasd-asdad-adds-rrewr/.sdfsf-sdfsd-adds-sdfsf.headless.keytab
    configparser:                   client=true
    configparser:                   useKeyTab=true
    configparser:                   useTicketCache=false
    configparser:                   serviceName=kafka
    configparser:   Reading next config entry: Client
    configparser:           com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule, REQUIRED
    configparser:                   principal=sdfsf-dsf-adds-uk@sfdsdf.ADROOT.ABC
    configparser:                   debug=true
    configparser:                   doNotPrompt=true
    configparser:                   keyTab=/home/sdfdsf-sfds-adds-sdf/.sdff.sdsfs-adds-usdfs.headless.keytab
    configparser:                   useKeyTab=true
    configparser:                   useTicketCache=false
    configparser:                   serviceName=zookeeper
    Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /home/dasda-sasd-adds-asdad/.asdad-asd-adds-adsasd.headless.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is dhsjdf-ssdf-adds-usdff@sdfs.ADROOT.ABC tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
    principal is usdfsf-ss-adds-ufsdf@sdfs.ADROOT.ABC
    Will use keytab
            [LoginContext]: login success
    Commit Succeeded

            [LoginContext]: commit success
    14:44:56.748 [main] WARN  o.a.k.c.producer.ProducerConfig - The configuration 'zookeeper.connect' was supplied but isn't a known config.
    adds in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.Timeoutadds: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.
Thanks,
Mahendra Tonape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were unable to consume message from consumer side at our cluster but we are able to consume messages at our local machine that is because we wrote our application api's using Kafka 0.10 and our cluster is having kafka version 0.9.If you checked differences between these 2 Kafka version you will find that there are significant differences between these 2 version API's.

Also please enable Kerberos debug Logs to check whether user is authenticaed with Kerberos enabled cluster